How to use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum value with constraints?
How can the Lagrange multipliers method be employed to optimize the function?$f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1^p+x_1^p)^{1/p}$
subject to the constraint $g(x_1,x_2)=p_1x_1+p_2 x_2-y=0$
I am a beginner, and the results obtained using the following code do not seem to be correct.
Clear[f, g]

f[x1_, x2_] := (x1^p + x2^p)^(1/p)
g[x1_, x2_] := p1 x1 + p2 x2 - y

Solve[
 D[f[x1, x2] - lambda g[x1, x2], {{x1, x2, lambda}}] == 0,
 {x1, x2}, lambda
]

The tool I am using is Mathematica.
update:
$ 0<p<1 ; p1>0 ; p2>0 ; y >0 $ and $ x1>0 ; x2>0$
update:
From the first-order condition:
$$
{\mathrm{x}_1}^{p-1}\left( {\mathrm{x}_1}^p+{\mathrm{x}_2}^p \right) ^{\frac{1}{p}-1}-\lambda \mathrm{p}_1=0
\\
{\mathrm{x}_2}^{p-1}\left( {\mathrm{x}_1}^p+{\mathrm{x}_2}^p \right) ^{\frac{1}{p}-1}-\lambda \mathrm{p}_2=0
$$
After simplifying appropriately:
$$\mathrm{x}_1=\mathrm{x}_2\left( \frac{\mathrm{p}_1}{\mathrm{p}_2} \right) ^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$$
Substituting the expression $y=\mathrm{p}_1\mathrm{x}_1+\mathrm{p}_2\mathrm{x}_2$
Eventually, we obtain:
$$\mathrm{x}_1=\frac{y\left( \mathrm{p}_2 \right) ^{\frac{1}{p-1}}}{\left( \mathrm{p}_1 \right) ^{\frac{p}{p-1}}+\left( \mathrm{p}_2 \right) ^{\frac{p}{p-1}}}$$
If Mathematica is not proficient in solving such problems, then, during the aforementioned solving process, what aspects can Mathematica assist us in simplifying?

The command of Maple 2024 (Student:-MultivariateCalculus:-LagrangeMultipliers((x1^p + x2^p)^(1/p), [p1*x1 + p2*x2 - y], [x1, x2], output = detailed) assuming (0 < p, p < 1, p1::real, p2::real, y::real)) results in a long and useless answer.

first line typo

@user64494 Thank you, but I am using Mathematica.

What are the constraints on the parameters p1 etc.? Without constraints this is unlikely to have a solution. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't have any solutions at all.

@SjoerdSmit p1 can be considered as a symbolically represented constant. In specific examples, it can take on any positive number such as 1, 2, 3, and so on. Similarly, p2 and y are also of this nature. Can Mathematica not find a symbolically generalized solution?

@lemmingxuan: You wrote "Thank you, but I am using Mathematica". I'd like to notice that the question doesn't have a simple answer, no more and no less.

Your edited question cannot be answered by Lagrange multiplers. As Wiki says Lagrange multipliers do not take into account $x1>0 ; x2>0$. KKT conditions should be used to this end.

@user64494 is wrong, as the Wiki they cited clearly explains. They don't seem to understand that if you have a problem specified by conditions $P(x)$ and extra conditions $Q(x)$, then a solution $x_$ to $P(x)$, such that $P(x_)$ is true, then it would be a solution to $P(x) \wedge Q(x)$ if $Q(x_*)$ happened to be true. So a method for solving $P(x)$ is sufficient if you can determine when $Q(x)$ is true, which is trivial in the OP's problem. No need for a sophisticated method for $P \wedge Q$.

@MicaaelE2 You wrote " if you can determine when $ Q(x)$ is true, which is trivial in the OP's problem".  Unfortunately, your claim is ungrounded. I repeat the KKT conditions should be used here, Lagrange multipliers do not handle restrictions which are inequalities.

First, the methods available for solving equations with parameters in both the base and exponent are not robust. But they aren't nonexistent. I'm still surprised when they work. In this case, help was needed. Since, everything is positive, we can use PowerExpand, which makes things easier.
Another trick is to reduce the number of parameters.  Sometimes raising MaxExtraConditions has a similar effect of allowing the algorithms to obtain an answer, but at the expense of more calculation. In this case, it runs too long, similar to what others have said about the complexity. I didn't wait to see if it would work. The following is too fast not to embrace. Both dict and help are used to reduce the number of parameters to the point that Solve[] will get up off its behind and do some work.
Yet another trick is to note that $u^{1/p}$ is a monotonic increasing function. So optimizing $f=u^{1/p}$ is equivalent to optimizing $f^p$.
f[x1_, x2_] := (x1^p + x2^p)^(1/p);
fp[x1_, x2_] := (x1^p + x2^p);
g[x1_, x2_] := x1 + m x2 - m z;
dict = {m -> p2/p1, z -> y*p1/p2};

assum = 0 < p < 1 && x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && y > 0 && p1 > 0 && p2 > 0 && 
   z > 0 && m > 0;
lagrange = D[fp[x1, x2] - lambda g[x1, x2], {{x1, x2, lambda}}];
partialSol = Solve[lagrange == 0, {x1, x2, lambda}]
residual = 
  lagrange /. partialSol // Simplify[#, assum] &; (* {{<>, 0, 0}} *)
residual = First@First[PowerExpand@residual];  (* nonzero component *)
help = {m^(-1 + p) p -> mp, -1 + p -> a};
remainderSol = Solve[residual == 0 //. help, x2] /. Map[Reverse, help];
finalSol = FullSimplify[
     Join[partialSol /. First@remainderSol, remainderSol, 2],
     assum] /. dict // PowerExpand // FullSimplify[#, assum] &


Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
(*
{{x1 -> m (-(((x2^(1 - p))^(1/(1 - p)))^(1 - p))^((1/(1 - p))) + z), 
  lambda -> (p x2^(-1 + p))/m}}

{{x1 -> y/(1 + (p1/p2)^(p/(1 - p))), 
  lambda -> p (p1/p2)^p ((1 + (p1/p2)^(p/(-1 + p)))/y)^(1 - p), 
  x2 -> (p1 y)/((1 + (p1/p2)^(p/(-1 + p))) p2)}}
*)


Check with original formulation: The Lagrange multiplier will be different, and we can solve for it, although usually it's not needed.
origLagrange = D[f[x1, x2] - lam2 g[x1, x2], {{x1, x2, lam2}}];
partialSubLagr = origLagrange /. dict /. First@finalSol //
  PowerExpand // FullSimplify[#, assum] &;
lam2Sol = Solve[First@partialSubLagr == 0, lam2]


(*
{{lam2 -> ((1 + (p1/p2)^(p/(1 - p)))/y)^(
    1 - p) ((y/(1 + (p1/p2)^(p/(1 - p))))^
      p + ((p1 y)/((1 + (p1/p2)^(p/(-1 + p))) p2))^p)^(-1 + 1/p)}}
*)


partialSubLagr /. First[lam2Sol] //
  PowerExpand // FullSimplify[#, assum] &


(*  {0, 0, 0}  *)



That edited question cannot be answered by Lagrange multiplers. As Wiki says Lagrange multipliers do not take into account $x1>0 ; x2>0$. KKT conditions should be used to this end.

You're misreading Wiki. Lagrange is a local condition. The solution is clearly a critical point of the Lagrange function. It seems ridiculous to object to that. It's also ridiculous to object that a condition that applies to all critical point cannot be applied to some of them. Instead of reading Wikipedia, I suggest you take a multivariable calculus course. Every textbook I've used solves questions similar to the one in the OP, with examples of open constraints and closed constraints. Often they point out the issues when the objective function is not smooth or the domain is not compact.

MichaelE2 (@does not work): Sorry, your "The solution is clearly a critical point of the Lagrange function" is not grounded.BTW, I am PhD in math for ages.

@user64494 The last line in the answer above is {0, 0, 0}, which confirms. None of your claims are grounded, either.

My program has been consistently stuck at the remainderSol step, unable to produce results (my CPU is i9-13900KF). I have revised the issue, offering manual solution steps and insights. In this context, what processes can Mathematica assist us in streamlining?

@lemmingxuan I'm using V14.1 (Macbook Pro M1), and that step takes 0.01 sec on a fresh kernel for me.

Nice set of simplifications.

Regarding mention of KKT conditions, they are only relevant if x1 or x2 is zero at a critical point. A quick examination of the equations shows this cannot be the case.

@lemmingxuan What led me down the path in my answer was something like this test of Solve's ability: Solve[x^a - c (b - x)^a == 0, x]. Does that execute quickly for you? It's the basic form of equation. The solution can be converted to the one I obtained above.

@MichaelE2 After opening a new notebook later on, I was able to successfully run it and obtain results. This success may have been due to certain limiting conditions that interfered previously, causing my program to stall. However, your code appears overly complex to me, and I am uncertain how to learn in order to attain your level of expertise.

To use Lagrange Multipliers, you add the condition multiplied by a scalar (lam) to the original equation and set the derivates equal to zero. This together with the condition will give you the solution. Here we also know that p,p1,p2 are positive integres:
f[x1_, x2_] := (x1^p + x2^p)^(1/p)
g[x1_, x2_] := p1 x1 + p2 x2 - y
fun[x1_, x2_] = f[x1, x2] + lam g[x1, x2];
eq = {D[fun[x1, x2], x1] == 0, D[fun[x1, x2] == 0], 
  g[x1, x2] == 0, {p, p1, p2} \[Element] PositiveIntegers};
Reduce[eq, {x1, x2, lam}]

False

Therefore, this problem does not have a solution.

Maybe not analytical, but surely there exists solutions. You are trying to minimize the distance w.r.t. p-norm on a line given by the constraint. There must be a solution. Where I assume p>0 not infinity. And p1 p2 are some non zero numbers

{p,p1,p2} need not be PositiveIntegers , we only need to assume that {x1,x2}>0

I'm sorry, I forgot to add some default constraints. Could you please modify how to write the code according to my updated question? Thanks to @cvgmt 's reminder, I remembered that I forgot about these default constraints.

With the new constrains, it takes longer than I am willing to wait.

So, this implies that it is not suitable for such scenarios, right? That is indeed quite regrettable.

Minor point: The restrictions on p preclude this from being an actual norm.
